# JQuery Change Text on click Link

Tags: jquery, text, click

i want the text to change on click. the code works when i click any link but as soon as i click another one, nothing happens. jquery is new to me thats why im struggling with this.
thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#all-iso").click(function(){
        $("#news-h3-change").replaceWith("<h3>ALLE NEWS</h3>");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date-iso").click(function(){
        $("#news-h3-change").replaceWith("<h3>DATUM</h3>");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#actor-iso").click(function(){
        $("#news-h3-change").replaceWith("<h3>SCHAUSPIELER</h3>");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#film-iso").click(function(){
        $("#news-h3-change").replaceWith("<h3>FILM</h3>");
    });
});
```

Comment: The reason that nothing happens is because you are replacing `#news-h3-change`, thus removing it from the DOM.

Comment: you do not need all those `$(document).ready(function(){` just one

Comment: we would need to see the relevant HTML. you are most likely removing the IDs that are being used as selectors.

Comment: (1) You only need one $(document).ready(), and all other code should be in that function; (2) Use .html() instead of .replaceWith(). See David Jashi's answer below - he's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   var StatusBar;

   $(document).ready(function(){
      StatusBar = $("#news-h3-change");
      $("#all-iso").click(function(){
        StatusBar.html("ALLE NEWS");
      });
      $("#date-iso").click(function(){
        StatusBar.html("DATUM");
      });
      $("#actor-iso").click(function(){
        StatusBar.html("SCHAUSPIELER");
      });
      $("#film-iso").click(function(){
        StatusBar.html("FILM");
      });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove nested H3-s

Comment: You can cache $("#news-h3-change") into a variable - so this will act a little faster (less DOM traverses every time)

Comment: @Tamlyn: reasonable enough, thanks.

Comment: It even don't need to be a global variable. Just declared in a `ready` function.

Comment: @Tamlyn: Call it a bad habit, but I like cached vars to be accessible from other functions too.

Comment: LoL @Tamlyn in today's world, if declaring a variable saves time ... you wouldn't notice it. Most every system today, even the cheap Wally-World pc's have enough power to load even a whole Meg of JS data in no time flat, and I think DSL speeds are the minimum standard now. Chances you have to cater to someone running so slow you need to use those old time savers are less than 1%. Kind of like putting all your JS at the bottom, it's just plain out-dated. Good tip for cleanliness though I suppose. Though I don't like anything in the global, I'd say put it in a specific namespace Object. just me.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I'm used to save every byte and CPU cycle, as most of my code is intended to run on low-power and slow set-top boxes.

Comment: @DavidJashi : You're preaching to the choir, bruddah. My first "big" gig was designing, from material scratch even, custom touch-screen PC's connected to custom WiFi DVR's for law enforcement vehicles. That was in '06. Even then I didn't bother with JS file size as long as total collective for each page loaded with such was less than 1Mb. That's really not hard to do. So still, my point stands. The tech then was no where near what it is today. And if I can do it on simple machines at low-end prices on FULLY custom machines 7 years ago, you can do it today.

Comment: @DavidJashi : believe me, I know about CPU issues. Unlike many on here, I still remember programming in DOS and COBOL even!

Answer (score 4):

As I saw pointed out while answering, part of your problem is in `replaceWith`. It is replacing the entire h3 line, thus there is nothing with that ID after first click. Secondly, you don't have to call doc.ready so much. "One call to do it all". Finally, just going to give you an example of how you can shorten it all up, aka, the way I might do it:

## Working Example

```
$(function() {  //  same as $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#all-iso, #date-iso, #actor-iso, #film-iso").on("click", function(e) {
        var txt = "";
        switch ($(this).prop("id")) {
            case "all-iso":
                txt = "ALLE NEWS";
                break;
            case "date-iso":
                txt = "DATUM";
                break;
            case "actor-iso":
                txt = "SCHAUSPIELER";
                break;
            case "film-iso":
                txt = "FILM";
                break;
        }
        $("#news-h3-change").text(txt);
    })
})
```

Learn More:

- [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)
- [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [Document.Ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

---

As an alternative, you might set your text to an object, then use "in-array" like call to get text.  Soemthing like:

```
var h3Txt = {
    "all-iso": "ALLE NEWS",
    "date-iso": "DATUM",
    "actor-iso": "SCHAUSPIELER",
    "film-iso": "FILM"
}
$(function() {
    $("#all-iso, #date-iso, #actor-iso, #film-iso").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#news-h3-change").text(h3Txt[$(this).prop("id")]);
    })
})
```

### Much Shorter Example!

---

And if you're working with modern tech (expecting users to have HTML5 browsers, although most HTML4 browsers will handle the following fine) you could set the text variable as a "data" property of the HTML element it belongs too (highly recommended in today's market) thus making your JS even shorter.

#### Data Savvy Example

### HTML

```
<!--  would be something like the following, make note of data properties -->
<li id="all-iso" data-text="ALLE NEWS">all-iso</li>
<li id="date-iso" data-text="DATUM">date-iso</li>
<li id="actor-iso" data-text="SCHAUSPIELER">actor-iso</li>
<li id="film-iso" data-text="FILM">film-iso</li>
```

### JS

```
$(function() {
    $("#all-iso, #date-iso, #actor-iso, #film-iso").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#news-h3-change").text($(this).data("text"));
    })
})
```

***And*** make this function even better by putting a same class name between them and then using that class name to make selection. Something like:

```
<li id="all-iso" data-text="ALLE NEWS" class="text-clickables">all-iso</li>
<li id="date-iso" data-text="DATUM" class="text-clickables">date-iso</li>
```

then

```
$(".text-clickables").on("click", function(e) { $("#news-h3-change").text($(this).data("text")); });
```

#### Data Savvy Example using Class Name

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the element, so the next time you attempt to query for an element with the id 'news-h3-change' it doesn't exist. You would probably find it easier to just replace the inner text of the h3 tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#all-iso").click(function(){
        $("#news-h3-change").text("ALLE NEWS");
    });
    /* ... */
    $("#film-iso").click(function(){
        $("#news-h3-change").text("FILM");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.replaceWith() replaces all the element. When you do it first time, it is ok, but second time you just don't have anything to replace.

After first replace you don't have any element with id="news-h3-change", it was replaced.

Take a look at .html() method. It replaces only the content. [.html() link to read](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
$("#date-iso").click(function () {...})
```

into this

```
$(document).on('click', '#date-iso' function() {...})
```

And so on...

This will bind event listener to `document` instance instead to object which you are replacing.